# Using Android Account GUID for Customer List upload Google Adwords instead of Mobile Device ID

Tags: google-ads

So Adwords has the functionality to upload customer lists based on Mobile Device ID for audiences.
I got the ones for iOS, however when I tried to upload for Android, I got a bunch of formatting errors and those are correct but Google refuses to use them. 
So instead, I used Account GUID as the Mobile Device ID.

Is this viable?